# What is a wave-branch?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I am reading [an article](https://www.neutron-sciences.org/articles/sfn/abs/2011/01/sfn201112006/sfn201112006.html) about spin-wave theory. It says that if there are $L$ spins in a magnetic unit-cell then there will be $L$ spin-wave branches. I want to physically understand what is a wave branch? Is it something like a wave mode?

Answer (score 2):

You should be interpreting the phrase "spin wave branches" as "(spin wave) branches," not "spin (wave branches)."

The term *branch* refers to the fact that the dispersion relation does not associate each wavevector $\mathbf k$ with a single energy.  This phenomenon is not unique to spin waves; the dispersion relation for phonons in a diatomic chain has two branches, which we refer to as *optical* (high frequency) and *acoustic* (low frequency).

[image]

[Source](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/334/disprel.php)